# MISRA2004-12_8-3 rule has static analysis violation for RHS operand (32u - n) even with limits check

Tags: c, misra, parasoft

I am currently attempting to use parasoft software to fix static analysis violations for my code using MISRA C coding standards. My code initially had this function:

```
static inline uint32_t rotate_right(uint32_t val, uint32_t n)
{
    return (val >> n) | (val << (32 - n));
}
```

This causes a static analysis violation under the rule MISRA2004-12_8-3. The rule says

> The right-hand operand of a shift operator shall lie between zero and one less than the width in bits of the underlying type of the left-hand operand

The rule documentation states that this particular rule reports a violation if

> - the right-hand operand is a constant with negative value or with value that
>   exceeds the length (in bits) of the left-hand operand
> - the right-hand operand is not a constant and is not checked by specific
>   pattern

As I am not using a constant for the right-hand operand, MISRA-C rules dictate that I surround this statement with limit checks. MISRA-C also states that

> Use of an unsigned integer type will ensure that the operand is
> non-negative, so then only the upper limit needs to be checked (dynamically
> at run-time or by review). Otherwise both limits will need to be checked."

Since I am using an unsigned type, `uint32_t`, I only need to check the upper limits of the right-hand operand. However, for `val << (32u - n)`, I cannot have the value of `n` as `0u`. Therefore, I tried to resolve this violation by adding the following checks:

```
static inline uint32_t rotate_right(uint32_t val, uint32_t n)
{
    if (n == 0u)
    {
        return val;
    }
    else if ((n > 0u) && (n <= 31u))
    {
        return (val >> n) | (val << (32u - n)); 
    }
    else
    {
        return 0u;
    }
}
```

Doing so resolves the static analysis violation for `(val >> n)`, but the same violation is still reported for `(val << (32u - n))`.

Hence, my questions are:

1. The `if` statement clearly restricts the value of `n` to be less than `32u`. Consequently, `(32u - n)` will also have a value less than or equal to `32u`. Why is parasoft software still reporting an error for the right-hand operand being `(32u - n)` despite the limit check?
2. What is the correct way to resolve this violation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the MISRA-C document says, it is only sensible to check this dynamically at run-time or during code review. Which of course won't stop dysfunctional static analysers from trying to do it during static analysis anyway...

> Why is parasoft software still reporting an error for the right-hand operand being (32u - n) despite the limit check?

Likely because it is bugged and reports a false positive.

Unless of course it spotted that some caller-side code is providing an `n` which is larger than `32`. Some static analysers are able to give somewhat smarter warnings when they check the project as whole rather than individual translation units, one at a time.

> What is the correct way to resolve this violation?

Your original code is fine and apart from `32` -> `32u`, it is MISRA compliant. Don't clutter it up with defensive programming just to silence the potentially broken tool. Only add such checks if you have reason to believe that `n` will actually be zero or larger than 32.

For MISRA-C compliance, it should be sufficient to state that the case of a variable `n` will be covered by code review.

(To be picky, MISRA-C:2004 doesn't allow `inline` since it doesn't allow C99, you need MISRA-C:2012 for that.)

Comment: Alright, so the best way to deal with this is to keep the original code and just suppress it with remarks stating that this will be covered by code review? I don't think `n` will be 0 or larger than 32 in my case

Comment: @Alaiko Or just suppress it with the remark that the tool is broken. Given the average quality of MISRA-C checkers out there, you are going to need a routine for how to deal with false positives caused by tool bugs.

Comment: MISRA C:2004 Permits provides a mechanism that allows the use of inline